# Changing variable labels/legend in raster plot to discrete characters

Tags: ggplot2, plot, variable-assignment, raster, bins

I have just made a plot using raster data that consists of 6 different land types and fit them to polygon vectors. I'm trying to change the values on the continuous scale bar (1-6) to the names of each landtype (e.g. grasslands, urban, etc) which is what each different colour represents. I have tried inserting breaks, however then each box in the legend contains labels (1-2, 2-3, 3-4 etc.)
[Raster plot where each diff colour represents diff land type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3USr.png)

This is my code:
[rasterxpolygonplotcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQsbN.png)

Comment: A proper question should include a *minimal self-contained reproducible example*, that is, add some data generated by code or that ships with R and show what you tried (and only include code relevant to the question at hand). Please do *not* include screenshots of code.

Answer (score 1):

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
cover <- c("forest", "water", "urban")
```

You can either do:

```
plot(r, type="classes", levels=cover)
```

Or first make the raster categorical

```
levels(r) <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("forest", "water", "urban"))
plot(r)
```